# Visio Web Drawings out of focus when embeded within Visio Web Access Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, 2016, visio-services

we are using Visio Web drawings for our documentation and embed them on pages using the Visio Web Access Web part.

For some reason, they seam to be completley out of focus.

**Additional Information:**

- Web Part is configured to fit in the whole drawing
- Zoom is disabled
- We are using SharePoint Server 2016 on Premise

Does anyone know, why its doing this?
When viewed in Visio or not embeded, the diagram Displays fine.

Answer (score 1):

The "Fit all shapes in view" ensures that the full diagram displays within the bounds of the web part. It will automatically resize the diagram of Visio to fit current web part size.

You can increase the Height of the web part to display the full diagram in larger size.

(By default, the width is auto, adjust width to fit zone. You can also set the Width if you want.)

Edit Visio Web Access web part, -> Under “Appearance” section:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you response. Sadly this does not seem to fix my problem.
I am already Setting the height of the web Part. Also I set "Fit Diagram in Window" and do not allow scaling.
With those settings, the diagram will still look blury.